# Font awesome icon not centering

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

JS: http://jsfiddle.net/1cmtpnha/

**I have this:**

```
  <div class="card-body">
   <div class="padding_5">
    <div class="icon-center">
      <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

`padding_5` just contains padding css
`card-body` is bootstrap 4

**I tried this:**

```
[class*="icon-"] {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

.icon-center i {
  text-align: center;
}
```

**and this:**

```
.icon-center {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

and neither worked.  Those were top checked responses i saw on SO.

What is wrong with my code?

I want it to be horizontally centered within a card-body.

It's not the bootstrap either.  I tested it on a separate page with no css or card-body.  Still same issue.

Comment: Try <i class="fa fa-twitter text-center" aria-hidden="true"></i>

Comment: I know you have a lot of answers here, but the main point is that you don’t tell an item to be centered. You tell the container that it’s content is centered, therefore you’d need your `text-align: center;` to be on `.icon-center`, NOT `.icon-center i`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three options here

**1. Parent: `text-align: center`**

set `text-align: center` to `body`.

**2. Child: `display: block` and `text-align: center`**

set `display: block` to `.icon-center`.

**3. Child `display: block` , set `width` and `margin: auto`**

set `display: block` , `width: 20px` and `margin: auto` to `.icon-center`.

https://codepen.io/blackcityhenry/pen/WPexKp

Comment: I ended up having interfering class.  I had a global i class float left.  i did use your code though thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.icon-center {
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card-body">
   <div class="padding_5">
    <div class="icon-center">
      <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add text-align: center; to the parent card-body

```css
.card-body{
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}

.padding_5 {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" type="text/css" />

<div class="card-body">
  <div class="padding_5">
    <div class="icon-center">
      <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```